# Getting the cookie string key in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

When receiving a request in a Play application, I can print the cookies like so:

```
println(request.cookies)
```

and the result is something like this:

```
Map(PLAY_SESSION -> Cookie(PLAY_SESSION,bd5712f8fb6a7a43935e20f98d6b147181dda9d5-inr=val1&uid=val2,None,/,None,false,true))
```

I just need the key `bd5712f8fb6a7a43935e20f98d6b147181dda9d5`, is there a way to get it in Play or I have to parse the string?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Cookie)

Comment: It doesn't mention how to get the key, am I missing it?

Answer (score 1):

you can get cookie value like this :

```
val cookieValue = request.cookies.get(KEY) match {
        case Some(cookie) => cookie.value
        case None => ""
}
```

if you want to get only keys

```
val cookieNames = request.cookies.map{cookie =>
cookie.name
}
```

Comment: I need the key (such as bd5712f8fb6a7a43935e20f98d6b147181dda9d5) not the cookie value

Comment: try this : request.cookies.foreach{cookie => cookie.name} , you can also use map instead of foreach. I have also updated my answer.

Comment: When I say key I don't mean the cookie key, but the string that Play uses to secure that the cookies are not hacked, such as bd5712f8fb6a7a43935e20f98d6b147181dda9d5, that's what I need. I know how to get the cookies.